# jQuery cute scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using **scrollTo plugin**, the excellent stuff.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

THe main idea - it must `start` to scroll the page **when we hover** `.top-scroll` block (mouseover) and `stop` **when we hover it out** (mouseleave).

Tryed this:

$(".top-scroll").hover(function(){
    $("body").scrollTo($(".top-corner"), 2000);
},function(){
    $("body").stop().scrollTo();
});

`Start` works, `stop` - not.

Anybody know, how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('.top-corner').offset().top},2000);` instead of scrollTo?